# How to SUM written data in SQL

Tags: sql, ms-access

I've been given a task for a college course I'm doing. The task is this:

The total number of courses in each Learning Area

I have a flat database that looks like this:

[image]

I tried to use SUM to count the Course Name column but of course, it can't because they aren't numerical values.

I've gotten as far as this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT [Learning Area] 
FROM DataFile;
```

So, the query returns all the unique Learning areas but how do I now count the number of courses for each learning area?

Any help or nudge in the right direction would be so appreciated.

Comment: Most people here want sample table data _and the expected result_ as formatted text, not as images. Also take a look at [mcve].

Comment: Hint: Do a GROUP BY, with COUNT().

Comment: @jarlh Thank you very much for the tips and I'll make sure to frame my questions this way in the future. Also thanks for the hint, I could complete the task because of this!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
SELECT [Learning Area], COUNT([Course Name]) FROM DataFile
GROUP BY [Learning Area]
```